# Install Magento1.x theme to Magneto 2.x version

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9, magento2, magento-2.0

I want to migrate my magento website store version 1.7 to 2.0.4.

First of all we are thinking to apply same theme as our existing website have, so the same look will for magento 2.x website also.

So I would like to know which steps are necessary to migrate complete store, 
Initially I am looking for just installing magento 1.7 theme into magento 2.

I check this [link](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/bk-frontend-dev-guide.html) but not able to figure out.

Is this possible ?

Any guidance please.

Answer (score 1):

As per magento 2 guide lines you can't migrate whole m1 to m2. you can only able to get the following details like "order","customer","promotion rule".

As far as your theme is concern your current m1 theme is not compatible with m2 as M2 totally changed in term of coding structure.

if you have purchased your current theme for m1 then you can have wording with your theme proving to find out whether they have ready theme for m2.

Make sure before migration cause m1 extension are also not compatible with m2.

Thanks

Comment: What if we copy css js images as per the M2 structure? Because we dont want to change website frontend for now, we want M2 functionality with same theme look. What do u think, how much time it will take to migrate fully customized M1 store to M2,  few months or year ?

Comment: It depends on how your store big. It may take several months as all extension are not available at the moment

Comment: Yes store is much more big. it has more than 9 Millions products. and fully customized, even lot of plugins are customized.

Comment: Then you have to wait until your extension are get developed in magento 2. Also if you have satisfy with my answer then upvote this

Answer (score 0):

First Thing First : get your self a development environment set up and migrate your current data i.e customer orders, products blar blar and then have a play in the development environment.

You can download the migration tools [HERE](https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool/releases)

Then write down a list of all your current M1 extensions and site features and then look for the equivalant extenion on M2 market place or get one built, or build your own.

Get all your business logic working on you the new M2 development site and then when you have your site functioning as it should with the data from your M1 site start to think about the theme and styling to match your M1 site and only when you are happy flick the switch!

Just make sure you test and test every site feature in M2, migrating from magento 1 to magento 2 is not easy but its just a matter of proper planning and when you get stuck just ask here on stack for help at each point.

Good look